# Create a manifest for nested PowerShell modules

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm having a minor issue with nested, PowerShell modules.

`Get-Module` correctly identifies the `ExportedCommands`, but the `ModuleType` is listed as `Script`, rather than `Manifest`:

```
PS>get-module

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Script     Bar                       Get-Bar
Script     Foo                       Get-Foo
```

Directory structure:

```
|-Modules
  |-Foobar
    |-Foobar.psd1
    |-Bar
      |-Bar.psm1
    |-Foo
      |-Foo.psm1
```

Foobar.psd1:

```
...
# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest
ModuleToProcess = ''

# Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in ModuleToProcess
NestedModules = 'Foo\Foo.psm1', 'Bar\Bar.psm1'
...
```

Have I structured the PSD1 file correctly?  In my situation, do I need a dummy/empty Foobar.psm1 file (with corresponding entry in PSD1 file)?  Do I need the nested directory structure, or can I just include the two PSM1 files (bar.psm1 and foo.psm1) in the parent directory (Foobar)?

Comment: This seems to work as expected on v3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directory structure needed to be:

```
|-Modules
  |-Foobar
    |-Foobar.psd1
    |-Bar.psm1
    |-Foo.psm1
```

Foobar.psd1 needed to be :

```
...
# Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in ModuleToProcess
NestedModules = 'Foo.psm1', 'Bar.psm1'
...
```

Comment: What should the RootModule be in this case?