# powershell module hierachy

Tags: c#, powershell

Stack,

Suppose I have multiple 3 powershell modules, called: `master.psm1`, `child1.psm1`, `child2.psm1` in the same local directory. I want to call `Import-Module` only on `master.psm1` and have `child1` and `child2` imported  as well.

Does powershell support this? I don't think this supported, but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the answer to this question (use nested modules in a .psd1 file):

[Create a manifest for nested PowerShell modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424171/create-a-manifest-for-nested-powershell-modules)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424171/create-a-manifest-for-nested-powershell-modules)